# svn: E170000: Unrecognised URL scheme for 'https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/ros/tags/ros-1.4.10'

Tags: ros, svn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when rosinstalling on my machine with svn 1.7.1, I get the following error:

```
svn: E170000: Unrecognised URL scheme for 'https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/ros/tags/ros-1.4.10'
```

The workaround is using svn 1.6. Is there any better workaround?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11721/svn:-e170000:-unrecognised-url-scheme-for-%27https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/ros/tags/ros-1.4.10%27/) by [Daniel Pinyol](https://answers.ros.org/users/470/daniel-pinyol/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2011-10-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd suggest asking about this on svn mailing lists.  It's not really a ROS problem.  A quick google of the error code finds a bunch of other references.  It may be a corrupted working copy, or a corrupted svn version.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I encountered the same problem. Make sure "neon" can be identified when trying to configure subversion.

---

Originally posted by [Johnny Shao](https://answers.ros.org/users/1563/johnny-shao/) with karma: 11 on 2011-12-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1